# segmentation fault occur on thread program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, ipc

I am new in thread program. I wrote a C program for executing threads which reverse the command line string and print the both original and reversed string. My program is here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *input_string;
    char *rev_string;
}data;

void* rev_string(void* arg)
{
    int len = 0,index1 = 0,
    index2 = 0;
    data* names = NULL; /*bject creation*/
    names = (data*)malloc(sizeof(data));
    if( NULL == names)
    {
        printf("malloc failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("thread recvd  = %s\n",(char*)arg);
    len = strlen((char*)arg);
    names->input_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    if( NULL == names->input_string)
    {
        printf("malloc failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strncpy(names->input_string,(char*)arg,len); /*copying input_string to the struct*/
    names->rev_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    if( NULL == names->rev_string)
    {
        printf("malloc failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(index1 = len-1 ; index1 >= 0 ; index1--)
    {
        names->rev_string[index2] = names->input_string[index1];
        index2++;
    }


    pthread_exit((void*)names);
}
```

Main program:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int no_of_strings = 0,
        len = 0,
        status = 0,
        ret = 0 ,
        index = 0;

    pthread_t id[index];  /*thread identifier*/
    void* retval = NULL; /*retval to store the value returned by thread job */

    data *strings = NULL;/*object creation*/

    if(1 >= argc)
    {
        printf(" please do enter the commands as of below shown format\n");
        printf("<exe.c> <string1> <string2> ...<string(N)>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    no_of_strings = argc - 1 ; /* no of strings entered */
    /*creation of threads*/
    for(index = 0; index < no_of_strings ;index++)
    {
        status = pthread_create(&id[index],NULL,rev_string,(void*)argv[index + 1]);

        if(status != 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR in creating thread\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("thread %d created\n",index+1);         }

    }

    for(index = 0 ;index < no_of_strings;index++)
    {
        ret = pthread_join(id[index],&retval);
        if(ret)
        {
            printf("Error in joining %d\n", ret);
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("the input_string = %s and its reverse = %s\n",((data*)retval)->input_string,((data*)retval)->rev_string);

    }

    //      free(retval->input_string);
    //      free(retval->rev_string);
    //      free(retval);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

It works on 2 string from command line argument. But got segmentation fault when more than strings. Why? Any errors? Help me.

Comment: This is no C++ and bad formatted (Please fix the tags and dispaly)

Comment: Ok..I removed that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pthread_t id[index];
```

`id` has zero length because `index == 0`. So any assignment to its elements is undefined behavior. Initialize the array with some positive length, e.g:

```
const int MAX_THREADS = 10;
pthread_t id[MAX_THREADS];  /*thread identifier*/
```

Comment: But after change index=1 starting from loop I got same error..I can display 2 strings.but after that got segmentation problem.after using gdb ..my argv[index] is null when reaching index is last string..so can't find string length and allocation...

Comment: @roger the problem is not in the loop, I made my answer clearer